# Absolute positioned span not resizing accordingly

Tags: php, dynamic, absolute

I'm developing a homepage using PHP, it has a menubar with dynamically loaded menu's. 
below the menubar is a div which i used to construct dynamic submenu which gets displayed on hover of menu on menubar.

Submenu is constructed in table and placed in span which is positioned absolutely with defined width and necessary left positioning. the problem is the width and position of span doesn't appears properly with change in screen resolution, it actually shrinks and appears some where else.

dynamically created submenu

```
<?php 
$menu_num = 1;
$left_pos = 316;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu_arr); $i++) {
    $desc   = "<table width = '100%' id = 'submenu_table' cellspacing = '7' > ";
    $result = mysql_query("select s.SUB_MENU_URL, s.SUB_MENU_DESC from $table_user_menu m, $table_sub_menu s where m.EMP_ID = '".$_SESSION['EMP_ID']."' and m.SUB_MENU_ID = s.SUB_MENU_ID and m.MENU_ID = $menu_arr[$i] order by s.DISPLAY_ORDER");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $temp = " < tr><td style = 'text-align:center;' ><a href =.".$row['SUB_MENU_URL']." style = 'text decoration:none;' > ".$row['SUB_MENU_DESC']."</a ></td ></tr > ";
        $desc = $desc.$temp;
    }
    $desc = $desc."</table > ";
    draw_submenu($desc, $menu_num, $left_pos);
    $left_pos += 141;
    $menu_num++;
}

function draw_submenu($desc, $menu_num, $left_pos)
{
    $left = $left_pos."px";
    echo " < span id = 'submenu".$menu_num."' class='drop_down_menu' style = 'left:$left' > ".$desc."</span > ";
}
?>
```

Submenu section must appear properly under Menu even when the screen resolution changes.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please make Jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

span is an inline tag, that cannot have a width. If you like to set one, you need to set it to a block element as well:

```
display: block
```

Or

```
display: inline-block
```

You could of course just use a div instead of a span, for that purpose.